# Only first element of Enum list is displayed instead of Entire list in Swagger

Tags: python, enums, yaml, swagger

Below is the generated YAML from python execution

```
requestBody:
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          properties:
            element_ids:
              items:
                type: string
              type: array
            element_type:
              items:
                enum:
                - NC
                - CELL
                type: string
              type: array
            expires_in:
              format: int32
              type: integer
            group_id:
              type: string
          required:
          - element_ids
          - element_type
          - expires_in
          - group_id
```

I have provided my enum values in the form of list.

I see only NC in the swagger(3.0.0) shown below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spec is correct. "Example Value" displays an *example* request based on the info you specified in the OpenAPI file. The full enum is listed on the **Schema** tab:

[image: Enum values listed on the "Schema" tab in Swagger UI.]

If you want to display `"element_type": ["NC", "CELL"]` in the JSON example, add the corresponding `example` to the `element_type` property definition:

```yaml
element_type:
  items:
    enum:
    - NC
    - CELL
    type: string
  type: array
  example: [NC, CELL]  # <----------
```