# Cant see scroll menu when working with enum

Tags: swagger, openapi

I want to define enum in `openAPI`.

I looked at this post:

[How to define an enum in OpenAPI (Swagger)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603871/how-to-define-an-enum-in-openapi-swagger)

and I want to be able to see the enum like:

[image]

I'm working with `components` and I define it as:

```
components:
  
  schemas:
  
    FilterImg:
      type: object
      properties:
          name:
            type: string
            enum: ["img_1", "img_2"]
          value:
            type: string
```

And I'm using it:

```
post:
      summary: Add new img
      tags:
        - img
      description: Lets a user post a new img
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/FilterImg'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successfully
```

But I can't see the enum as enum scroll menu (in the web browser), as we can see it in the example.

What am I missing ?

Comment: What are you getting right now in output? Why you want to show `enum` in response? It will always show an object., and check your schema `FilterImg` you have defined its `type: object` so it will show in object view

Comment: Check the "Schema" tab in the response.

Comment: i updated the code (set the enum in post and not in get)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only first element of Enum list is displayed instead of Entire list in Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54104552/113116)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `application/json` in content type and you want `enum dropdown` how its possible?

You need to learn more about swagger from this documentation [Swagger Docs](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/about/) and [Openapi Specification](https://swagger.io/specification/),

Anyway i got an idea, you need this dropdown in body so here i have just added in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type:

```yaml
post:
  summary: Add new img
  tags:
    - img
  description: Lets a user post a new img
  requestBody:
    required: true
    content:
      application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/FilterImg'
  responses:
    '200':
      description: Successfully
```

Remaining things will be same.

It will looks like:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In case of JSON/XML request and response bodies, the enum values for individual body fields are displayed in the schema documentation, that is on the **Schema** tab (or **Model** tab in case of OpenAPI 2.0).

[image: Enum values for a JSON body field]

Comment: Dear @Helen, i respect you, the questioner need a scroll menu, for particular image choices or selection purpose, your pointed schema view will just view it will not allow to select particular choice, if i am wrong can you please explain how its my answer not useful?